# Extract string separated by semi-colon in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a column with the researchers' affiliations and want to extract only those affiliations from `Brazil`.

Here is an example:

```
"Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; School of Health Sciences, Faculty of Medicine and Health Sciences, University of East Anglia, Norwich, United Kingdom; Human Cognitive Neuroscience, Psychology, University of Edinburgh, Edinburgh, United Kingdom; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

The following result is expected:

```
"Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

Comment: Só tem fera nessa lista de autores, diga-se de passagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use regex to remove the part of string that does not contain 'brazil':

```
 gsub("(^|;)((?![^;]+Brazil).)+", "\\1", str, perl = TRUE)

[1] "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

where

```
str <- "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; School of Health Sciences, Faculty of Medicine and Health Sciences, University of East Anglia, Norwich, United Kingdom; Human Cognitive Neuroscience, Psychology, University of Edinburgh, Edinburgh, United Kingdom; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

---

#### Edit

To only extract the university names, do:

```
gsub("(^|;)((?!University[^;]+Brazil).)+", "\\1", str, perl = TRUE)

[1] "University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil;University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil;University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil;University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil;University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil;University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

---

Using `stringr` package

```
str_c(unlist(str_extract_all(str, "University[^;]+Brazil")), collapse=';')
[1] "University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil;University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil;University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil;University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil;University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil;University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

The previous code in stringr

```
str_c(unlist(str_extract_all(str, "[^;]+Brazil")), collapse=';')
[1] "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please help now to extract only the university name. I want the following result: University of São Paulo; University of São Paulo; University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges; Federal University of Minas Gerais; Federal University of Minas Gerais; University of Campinas; University of Campinas

Comment: @AriAlex add the word university in your pattern eg `gsub("(^|;)((?!University[^;]+Brazil).)+", "\\1", str, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
str <- "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; School of Health Sciences, Faculty of Medicine and Health Sciences, University of East Anglia, Norwich, United Kingdom; Human Cognitive Neuroscience, Psychology, University of Edinburgh, Edinburgh, United Kingdom; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"

do.call("paste", 
        strsplit(str, ";") |> 
          lapply(function(x) grep("Brazil", x, value = TRUE)) |>
          c(collapse = ";"))
#> [1] "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please help now to extract only the university name. I want the following result: "University of São Paulo; University of São Paulo; University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges; Federal University of Minas Gerais; Federal University of Minas Gerais; University of Campinas; University of Campinas"

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `stringr` package. First, split the string on the ";" character with `str_split_1`. Second, filter the character vector with `str_subset`. Finally, "flatten" the string back together with `str_flatten`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

authors <- "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; School of Health Sciences, Faculty of Medicine and Health Sciences, University of East Anglia, Norwich, United Kingdom; Human Cognitive Neuroscience, Psychology, University of Edinburgh, Edinburgh, United Kingdom; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"

authors |> 
    str_split_1('; *') |> 
    str_subset('Brazil') |>
    str_flatten(collapse = ';')

[1] "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil;Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil;Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil;Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil;Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil;Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `scan` + `grep` like below

```
paste0(
    grep("Brazil", 
    scan(text = s, sep = ";", what = ""), value = TRUE),
    collapse = ";"
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```

## Data

```
s <- "Department of Neurology, Faculty of Medicine, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Gerontology, School of Arts, Sciences, and Humanities, University of São Paulo, São Paulo, Brazil; Graduate Program in Applied Statistics, University Center of United Metropolitan Colleges, São Paulo, Brazil; School of Health Sciences, Faculty of Medicine and Health Sciences, University of East Anglia, Norwich, United Kingdom; Human Cognitive Neuroscience, Psychology, University of Edinburgh, Edinburgh, United Kingdom; Neurology Division, University Hospital, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, Brazil; Neuroimaging Laboratory, School of Medical Sciences, University of Campinas (UNICAMP), Campinas, Brazil; Neurology Department, University of Campinas, Campinas, Brazil"
```